# ZeroMQ pattern for Worker processes?

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm just learning 0MQ and am having difficulty understanding which pattern to use for my use case.

I want to create a server to which multiple clients will connect. The server is going to hand out work items, but each work item will have to go to a specific client. For example, if the server were picking cards from a deck, I would want all hearts to go to one worker, all diamonds to a second worker, etc. (The work items are actually events from sessions, and I need every event for a single session to go to the same worker.)

What pattern do I use for this, and does anyone have any code that shows something like (in Python):

```
context = zqm.Context()
socket = context.socket(which type?)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

#wait for 4 clients to connect (how?)

while True:
    card = GetNextCard()
    if card.suit == HEARTS:
        send card to Worker #1 (how?)
    if card.suit == DIAMONDS:
        send card to Workder #2
    etc...
```

Basically, how do I track the clients that have connected to the server, and send work items to only one of n clients that are connected?

Comment: This sounds like the Majordomo Pattern (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc98).

Answer (score 0):

### Welcome to the world of Distributed-computing:

Clients may introduce themselves, once starting to get connected to the server,
 assume a server to have

```
SUB_to_Ask4Connect = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
SUB_to_Ask4Connect.bind(                "tcp://A.B.C.D:P" )
SUB_to_Ask4Connect.setsockopt(       zmq.LINGER, 0 )
SUB_to_Ask4Connect.setsockopt(       zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )
#------------------------------------------------------ ready to .recv() from *
```

### Next, establish a Client-accept-into-WorkerPoolPOLICY():

so as to handle the right newcomer, who has introduced via the above setup `SUB_to_Ask4Connect` socket-interface.

Clients ought know the protocol of -
**a)** `.connect()` to the proper address
**b)** `.send()` their proper self-introduction
**c)** be ready to `.connect()` / `.bind()` to additional socket interfaces, as per
server's instructions to do so
**d)** have a `.bind()`-ready ( or a `.connect()`-to a known server-side reverse-`PUB`, if security requirements permit ) interface to receive further details and handshaking signalisation, during the WorkerPool-assignment/coordination/release policies, that are work-package specific and server-side controlled.

Simply said, do not expect a single archetype to match all the requirements for such a distributed control of ad-hoc work-package routing with having also a dynamic ad-hoc client-association/release in-place.

Such distributed-pool(s) system control-plane is more important and cardinal for such a dynamic eco-system, than the much simpler work-package logistics plane ( where just much simpler handshaking takes place ).

Anyway, you will enjoy this new Universe -- where distributed entities appear / disappear and ( may ) cooperate in a new way, not common to the monolythic architectures and architects.

**Feel free to [browse other ZeroMQ questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A3666197%20%5Bzeromq%5D%20is%3Aanswer) and answers to find even more inspirative insights.**